# "raw sewage" vs. "raw sewerage"

Tags: vocabulary

> In addition, sewage treatment plants in Baghdad were so badly damaged during or after the war that no *raw sewerage* is being treated. (The New York Times)

After having searched for on some online dictionaries, I'm still unsure whether "raw sewerage" is correct or not.

In Merriam Webster's definition of "raw",

> 2a (1) : being in or nearly in the natural state : not processed or purified "raw fibers" "raw sewage"

it is written "raw sewage", but, I suppose, this circumstance doesn't exclude the correctness of "raw sewerage".

Problem is that I found only a few occurences of "raw sewerage" on reliable sources.

Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 6):

If you look at Merriam Webster's definition of sewerage it includes

> 3: sewage

So according to Merriam Webster "sewerage" can be a synonym of "sewage". In the sentence you quoted this is what is meant.

The OED indicates that this usage is restricted to American English, and the lack of hits for "raw sewerage" versus "raw sewage" suggests it is rarely used at all in writing.

So strictly speaking the sentence is correct but not something you'd want to emulate.

Comment: MW tends to provide a link to another word, rather than a definition, when the word in question is a nonstandard variant (cf. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irregardless). MW's top definitions for "sewerage" are that it is "the removal and disposal of sewage and surface water by sewers" or "a system of sewers"; "sewage" is "refuse liquids or waste matter usually carried off by sewers". So, yes, one would do well to avoid "sewerage" as a synonym for "sewage"!

Answer (score 4):

*Sewage*, at least in the UK, is the normal term for the contents of sewers. *Sewerage* has been used with the same meaning in the past, but it can also describe a system of sewers.

Comment: That’s exactly as I would use those two.  The last one is rare, but might well mean the system you speak of.

Answer (score 2):

I work for a wastewater organisation in Australia but the meaning of sewer, sewage and sewerage is consistent across the English speaking world. A *sewer* is a pipe that has *sewage* flowing through it. A network of sewer pipes is called a *sewerage* network. Therefore, if you see a pile of muck that has overflowed out of the sewer, that is a *raw sewage* overflow. *Raw sewerage* could only mean that the pipes haven't been cooked or something. We always laugh at people who complain about *raw sewerage* overflows for two reasons: (1), they usually mean sewage; and (2), sewage only gets treated at the end of the network, so any sewage that overflows before then will always be raw. In short, the New York Times got this one wrong.

Comment: Not exactly... Merriam Webster, at least, acknowledges that misuse has led to common enough usage of "sewerage" for "sewage" (see Nigel Harper's answer).